# If a picture of a screen is a screenshot, what is a video of a screen?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, computing, telephone

I'm looking for a catchy and nice-sounding word. A really nice sounding phrase would although be better than nothing.

I record my computer screen a lot and never really found a nice word to describe it like a *screenshot*. I also searched the web a lot and found nothing about it.

Example:

> My mom: How do I get to the settings on my phone?
>   
>   Me: I'll send you a _____(recording of my screen) so you can see how I get there.

"screen recording" is my favorite, but I am still not really satisfied. (UPDATE: I found a [video of someone famous saying screen recording](https://youtu.be/RY_2gElt3SA?t=6), I would appreciate if you comment with links to more videos like this with your favorite choices)...   I also found about [100 videos on YouTube of people using this term](https://youglish.com/pronounce/screen%20recording/english?), which I have not found for any of the alternatives mentioned in the question.

That said I did not find it on [Lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/en).

[Here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/TRF1ZJNTvxjeKwEG6) is a "screen recording" showing that "screenshot" is on Lexico.com, but "screen recording" is not.

Options I found unsatisfying:

screencast, screencap, videoshot, screenshots, screenmotionpicture, screenselfie, Screengif.

*screencap* is not common ***and*** confusing on top of that - [here](https://youglish.com/pronounce/Screencap/english?) are some videos showing how this is used wrongly.

*screencast* is commonly used in certain fields (tech, design, photography, media and probably more). [Here](https://youglish.com/pronounce/screencast/english?) are a lot of videos showing this. My issue with this word is that it is very misleading and it will definitely confuse *many* people. [@jmbpiano](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/222378/jmbpiano) put this very nicely in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/520049/if-a-picture-of-a-screen-is-a-screenshot-what-is-a-video-of-a-screen#1263919) on the answer [screencast](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/520049/if-a-picture-of-a-screen-is-a-screenshot-what-is-a-video-of-a-screen#answer-520052) :

> This usage seems rather niche and if I were to first encounter it in
>   another context, the suffix "-cast" would immediately evoke mental
>   comparisons to "broadcast" and "webcast" (forms that are decidedly not
>   static, playable on-demand video, but rather something that is being
>   presented once at a specific time, possibly live and/or interactive).

Comment: Why did you find 'screencast', defined in Collins as 'a digital recording of the display on a computer screen that may be viewed on another device', unsatisfying?

Comment: Because no one I know understood what it means. A cast is more like something live to me and recording fits better. But both just don't sound smooth enough in general.

Comment: Technically, a computer "screen" **is** always a video stream. So your question is akin to asking "what is a video of a 'video stream'". A video of anything is "recording". Recording of a screen. Recording of a screencast. Recording of a movie.

Comment: **Cheeky answer**: "screenshoot".

Comment: Another cheeky answer : a bootleg.

Comment: Screen recording is usually what any software displays, it also makes sense to me.

Comment: Why not just video / recording? When I have to send my mother a screencap, I don't go into technical terms and just say video. It's still correct, albeit a general term.

Comment: I'd just rather be specific, using the same logic you can say picture and you don't have to say screenshot. But you're right I could do that.

Comment: @user21820 Heh, I actually quite like that...

Comment: @Chagai Friedlander: Are you looking for terms that are already in use? If so, it would help to add that. I see several respondents making suggestions without specifying whether they are in use.

Comment: @reinerpost I'm looking for terms which are either in use or can be understood easily. I thought that was clear from the question.

Comment: I updated the question, hope the question and the problem with some of the answers are clear now.

Answer (score 47):

***Screencast***

Similarly to many commenters here, I actually don't like this word much. Personally, I would probably use *video capture.* Individual tastes aside, however, *screencast* is a term that is very well attested in dictionaries, books, and software, and if you look at the evidence below, seems to be preferred overall.

Let's start with the

**Dictionaries**

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/screencast) (with thanks to  Edwin Ashworth):

> a digital recording of the display on a computer screen that may be viewed on another device

[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/screencast):

> a digital recording of computer screen output

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/screencast):

> a digital recording of a computer screen's display

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/screencast):

> **noun**
>   A video recording or transmission of the data displayed on the screen of a computer or mobile device, typically with accompanying audio.
>       ‘this tutorial contains a screencast demonstrating all of the steps’
>   
>   **verb** *(no object)*
>   Record or transmit video of data displayed on the screen of a computer or mobile device, typically with accompanying audio.

On the other hand, *screencast* is not recorded in the OED, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/screencast), [American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=screencast), or [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=screencast).

**Wikipedia**

Here is the lede of the Wikipedia article ["Screencast"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast):

> A ***screencast*** is a digital recording of computer screen output, also known as a video screen capture, often containing audio narration. The term screencast compares with the related term screenshot; whereas screenshot generates a single picture of a computer screen, a screencast is essentially a movie of the changes over time that a user sees on a computer screen, enhanced with audio narration.

True, *in general,* one should not take Wikipedia as a reputable source. However, my experience is that tech-related topics are *usually* treated quite authoritatively there, at least once the article has existed for a number of years (as this one has).

**Use in published literature**

Here are some books that use that terminology:

***Screencasting*** for Libraries [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=2inBg7T2XqQC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PP1&dq=screencast&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=screencast&f=false)
*The Use of **Screencasting** in Higher Education: A Case Study* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=F0JvDwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT102&dq=screencast&pg=PA1#v=onepage&q=screencast&f=false)
*iPad in Education For Dummies*

> **Screencasting** on desktops and laptops has been around for a number of years. **Screencast** software records whatever is displayed on your screen and enables you to add a voiceover narration during the recording. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=L0nyAwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA286&dq=screencast&pg=PA286#v=onepage&q=screencast&f=false)

*Sixth Grade Technology Curriculum: 32-lesson Comprehensive Curriculum*

> Have **screencast** and screenshot tools available as software, web-based tools, or add-ons. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=NRNDgEgd1LsC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA96&dq=screencast&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q=screencast&f=false)

**Use in software applications**

Here are some examples of video capturing applications that use that term.

[Kazam](https://launchpad.net/kazam) on Linux:

[image]

An example from [Adobe](https://www.adobe.com/products/captivate/screen-recording.html?gclid=CjwKCAiAlajvBRB_EiwA4vAqiIJa_-HQkDIIYkBUL1x_AYtA-fqpWam6dG3t23KZXh5mJVG095ne8RoCeJ4QAvD_BwE&sdid=TG8SLLXG&mv=search&promoid=70114000002XDiUAAW&ef_id=CjwKCAiAlajvBRB_EiwA4vAqiIJa_-HQkDIIYkBUL1x_AYtA-fqpWam6dG3t23KZXh5mJVG095ne8RoCeJ4QAvD_BwE:G:s&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!367793676659!p!!g!!screencast%20software):

[image]

Some other examples of software that uses this term: [Jing](https://www.techsmith.com/download/jing/), [Screencast-o-matic](https://screencast-o-matic.com/), [Bandicam](https://www.bandicam.com/screencast/)…

***Facebook*** uses the term *screencast* a lot in its pages for developers, i.e. [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps/sample-submission/)

> Next, you upload a **screencast** of your app and how it is using the permission.

and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit/)

> You can use any of these accounts to test your app and create a **screencast**.
>   How can I test my app and record a **screencast**?
>   Provide a **screencast.**

and

> Provide a Detailed **Screencast** and Clear Instructions = Quicker Evaluation
>
> Our review team examines your **screencast** and follows your usage instructions to reproduce the personalization elements of each permission. Providing a detailed **screencast** and clear instructions will result in quicker evaluation of your submission.

(With thanks to Andrew Leach.)

Comment: I have that in my question, but I guess this is the correct term, do people actually use it though?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander Oh, sorry didn't see it in the question. But it is definitely used, at least by *some* of people who write video capturing apps. See the examples in my answer. Also the fact that Wikipedia named the relevant article that way does count for something.

Comment: Thanks very much, but I'll wait a bit maybe something better comes up :)

Comment: It's certainly what Facebook use when you need to demonstrate a Facebook app to them for approval.

Comment: I can't argue with the facts you've supplied to demonstrate this has been used in the sense the question requests. At the same time, I would urge caution on the part of anyone using it with an audience not already familiar with the term. This usage seems rather niche and if I were to first encounter it in another context, the suffix "-cast" would immediately evoke mental comparisons to "broadcast" and "webcast" (forms that are decidedly *not* static, playable on-demand video, but rather something that is being presented once at a specific time, possibly live and/or interactive).

Comment: @jmbpiano I had the same 'mental comparison' as you when I first encountered this word, which, serendipitously enough, was only a few weeks ago! Also, many screencasting apps don't use that term, but instead use something like *screen recording.*

Comment: *Cast* implies that it's distributed to an audience, usually implied to be an audience of more than one. I would not call what OP is asking for a "screencast" unless that condition is met.

Comment: @R..That **would** make sense, but what makes sense is not always how things are. In particular, that's not how the word is used in many of the examples of usage, as shown in the answer. It is also not how it is defined in the two dictionaries (or, for what it's worth, on Wikipedia).

Comment: A screencast is *not* pre-recorded. It is always live at the time of recording and in the primary use case. I think should revise the answer to reflect this.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck What you are saying is contrary to the definitions in every dictionary I've been able to find that contains an entry for *screencast* (four major dictionaries), Wikipedia, software such as Kazam and Jing, Facebook instructions for app developers, and several published books. If you have even stronger evidence that says otherwise, please share it. (Note that, out of the four dictionaries, only Lexico mentions *transmission* —but it, too, mentions *recording*.)

Comment: I've only ever seen the term *screencast* used for a recording of what happens on a computer screen. It may logically incorrect, but it's how the word is used.

Answer (score 43):

I would call it a **video screen capture**. The Wikipedia article [screencast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screencast) says:

> A **screencast** is a digital recording of computer screen output, also known as a **video screen capture**, often containing audio narration. The term *screencast* compares with the related term *screenshot*; whereas a screenshot generates a single picture of a computer screen, a screencast is essentially a movie of the changes over time that a user sees on a computer screen, enhanced with audio narration.

Wikipedia not withstanding, to me a screencast is more likely to be a live presentation than a recording, or at least one with a distributed audience, *à la* a broadcast. If you're just sending it to your mother, I wouldn't call it any kind of -cast.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. AKA: "screencap". Edit: I'm speaking from the perspective of the tech industry, where "screencap" is a common word.

Comment: Or just "video capture".

Comment: @thanby Except that *screencap* by itself doesn't necessarily imply a **moving** image. Perhaps I'm just showing my age.

Comment: @AndrewLeach *From my experience** screencap does imply video, screen*grab* or screen*shot* refer to stills. But again, I don't have a technical reference for that, just what I've observed.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer so far but I still believe most people would understand screen recording better.

Comment: @CJ Dennis: Have you ever actually seen the term *screencast* used for a live display of a computer screen broadcast to viewers? I haven't. Are you describing how the word *is* used, or how it *ought to be* used?

Answer (score 22):

It's not 'screenrecording'; English doesn't use compound nouns as often as other Germanic languages.

'Screen recording', so two words, is generally used, e.g. in this QuickTime Player menu:

[image]

Why is the related term 'screenshot' just one word? Maybe because it's only two syllables? A widely used alternative for that is 'screen capture' and I always see it written with two words.

Comment: Thanks but I think that is more of a comment than an answer... do you have an alternative?

Comment: Compared to your own answer, this is a volume.

Comment: 'Inkwell', 'ink-well' and 'ink well' are all valid alternatives of the same compound noun. Whether 'screen recording' is a compound noun or a strong or loose collocation is a different issue.

Comment: There is a general trend of compound words starting out as two tokens and then becoming one, sometimes with a hyphenated middle step (e.g. "long sword" --> "long-sword" --> "longsword").  But it would be unusual for that to happen with a multisyllabic second token.

Comment: @KevinTroy You're completely correct. It does sometimes happen, but usually with some additional simplification involved. If, through the evolution of the language, this *were* to eventually become compounded, I would expect one or more syllables to quickly be dropped (e.g. "screencording") much the way "simultaneous broadcast" has evolved into "simulcast".

Comment: Screenshot may also have taken hold because of its alliteration.

Comment: *Screen recording* is a compound noun.

Answer (score 12):

**Screencap**, <strike>first</strike> mentioned here in thanby's comment on CJ Dennis's answer:

> This is the most correct answer. AKA: "screencap". Edit: I'm speaking from the perspective of the tech industry, where "screencap" is a common word.

is the correct word for this. Screen*cast* is not; it implies *broadcast*, usually live, usually to a wider audience. [Video] screen capture is okay-ish, but "screencap" is how it's usually said.

Update: As noted in your comment, you mentioned screencap as a word you didn't choose in the question. However I really do think it's the right word here. It's what's used by people who do commonly deal with this and have a word for it, and even if someone hasn't heard it before, it immediately makes sense and is memorable once they hear it used.

Comment: It was actually also mentioned in the question.

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander: Oh, I completely missed that.

Comment: This is my favorite answer so far, I'll test this a bit in the real world and then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: As an IT support person, I've never seen this term. It would help to clarify which tech industry where uses this term.

Comment: I think searching some video platforms (as well as just Google) for this and different candidate terms would shed light on what's actually in use. (Note: I haven't done this.)

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I have just done this and I believe this is a confusing term, I think I'm back to screen recording.

Comment: I found nothing on [Youglish](https://youglish.com) for [screencap](https://youglish.com/pronounce/Screencap/english?) as a video recording so I unmarked this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about "I'll send you a clip so you can see how I get there." Or the term "video clip." They both indicate a portion of a longer video sequence.

Comment: This doesn't imply having to do anything with the screen...

Answer (score 3):

Why among all these answers has **screengrab** not yet been suggested?

The reason I especially like it is that the Spanish verb "grabar" means to record.

And "grabar" comes from French "graver" - meaning "to engrave": a form of recording
(Which itself arrived from the German "graben": to dig or burrow)

Comment: I thought graben means dig in German.

Comment: I must admit that I don't know German, and was only going on what I had read of the etymology of the Spanish. Will update my answer...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>***Screenrecording***</strike>  ***screen recording***.

This was in the question, but still seems like the best option for non-technical folk.

Comment: My main objection to this answer isn't the fact that it is given by the OP and that it repeats information in the Q. My main objection is that this A suggests "screenrecording" which is very strange English. In English, you don't combine words without a space like you do in German, Swedish, etc. So "screen recording" is OK, but "screenrecording" deserves a downvote IMHO -- it's bad English.

Comment: How did screenshot then come about? I still think it's the best option and that I what most people will understand without me having to refer to a wiki page to explain.

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander - No, that would be "screencast," which is the common word for this. "Screen recording" (two words) is clear, but not a *term* per se, more a description. About "screenshot" -- as noted elsewhere, although English doesn't do the German thing nearly as readily, we *do* do it over time, usually when the second word is one syllable (example elsewhere is "long sword" => "long-sword" => "longsword"). Other times a word is just coined in one go, as I suspect was the case with screenshot (but I haven't researched that suspicion).

Comment: "Recording of my screen" is a reasonable non-technical way to say it, but "screen recording" is not a standard technical term, but follows the habit of technical language of coining new noun phrases, so sounds technical.

Answer (score 0):

How about "animated screenshot"? It sounds good especially if the stream is mute.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please try to add references to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually just "video" or "video capture". Why needlessly try to complicate a basic and simple concept?

Unlike some have suggested, it isn't a "video screen capture". You are looking at a video screen now, so a video screen capture would be ambiguous, as either a still-picture (screenshot) or a video would fit that description... obviously!

Answer (score -3):

The word you are looking for is "Screenshoot". Shot gives the sense of having already occurred in a single instant, fitting well with the action of taking a single picture. Shoot gives the sense of occurring currently in continuum, fitting well with the action of taking a video.

That is my favorite, although I also thought of the words "screenstream", "streamshot", and "screen-cine".

Comment: Can you cite any of those words?

Comment: "Screenstream" is a tongue twister.

Comment: *Shoot* doesn't mean something that is shot, so *screenshoot* doesn't readily fit into English idiom. *Screenshot* does, and it is actually used, but only for still pictures as far as I know.